# Value does not fall within the expected range when try to get field values

Tags: column

I try to send the selected documents in my library to the **RMA**. I got the following exception

> Value does not fall within the expected range

What is my issue? Do I need to get the field by `staticName`?

```
foreach (string itemID in itemIdArray)
{
  SPListItem item = list.GetItemById(Convert.ToInt32(itemID));
  SPFile file = item.File;
  byte[] bytes = file.OpenBinary();
  string fileType = file.Item.ContentType.Name;

  // Create a RecordsRepositoryProperty for each metadata field.
  SPFieldCollection fields = file.Item.Fields;
  List<RecordsRepositoryProperty> properties = new List<RecordsRepositoryProperty>();
  foreach (SPField field in fields)
  {
      try
      {
          string value = Convert.ToString(
          field.GetFieldValue(Convert.ToString(file.Item[field.Title])));

          RecordsRepositoryProperty property =
          new RecordsRepositoryProperty
          {
              Name = field.Title,
              Type = field.TypeAsString,
              Value = value
          };

          properties.Add(property);
      }
      catch (Exception ex)
      {
          LoggingHelper.Write(LoggingCategories.BWSiteDefinitions, TraceSeverity.Unexpected, string.Format("Document properties opslaan is niet goed gegaan voor property {0}", field.Title), ex);
      }
  }
}
```

In the uls I see 2 errors like this:

```
at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFieldMap.GetColumnNumber(String strFieldName, Boolean bThrow)    
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPListItemCollection.GetRawValue(String fieldname, Int32 iIndex, Boolean bThrow)    
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPListItem.GetValue(SPField fld, Int32 columnNumber, Boolean bRaw, Boolean bThrowException)    
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPListItem.GetValue(String strName, Boolean bThrowIfValueMissing, Boolean bThrowIfFieldMissing)    
 at MyNameSpace.SendFileToRMA(String listID, String[] itemIdArray)
```

And I see 7 times this error:

```
at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFieldLookupValue.ParseLookupId(String fieldValue)    
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFieldLookupValue..ctor(String fieldValue)    
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFieldLookup.GetFieldValue(String value)    
 at MyNameSpace.SendFileToRMA(String listID, String[] itemIdArray)
```

Comment: Are all the itemIDs in your itemIdArray valid ? Have you verified that?

Comment: yes, thats not my issue because otherwise I will get an object null reference error on row 4. On my dev it was working fine. After deploy it to the Test environment I got these errors.